# How to get Format-Table to truncate when output goes to console but not truncate when output goes to file?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Maybe the real question here is can you detect that your output is being redirected to a file?

I have something in my script along the lines of:

```
$table | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Let's say my script is called Print-Table.

I want the columns of the Table to be truncated when I do:

```
.\Print-Table
```

However, I want to have the columns be fully expanded when I do:

```
.\Print-Table > table.txt
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd dump to a CSV file instead, and then format that as appropriate in another tool (Excel).

Answer (score 0):

The redirection happens outside your script, so no, you can't detect it. You could make the filename an argument to the script, though, and redirect/auto-size inside the script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter()]
  [string]$Filename
)

if ($Filename) {
  ... | Format-Table > $Filename
} else {
  ... | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```